# Row and Column grouping buttons have disappeared on certain sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have lost the grouping buttons and leader lines for column and row groupings on certain sheets in a workbook. Have tried the following without any success:

- Display options (Options>Advanced) - 'Show outline symbols if an outline is applied' is checked on all sheets.
- Applying auto outline to affected sheets
- Resaving as .xlsb/.xlsm
- Opening with Excel 20017 (currently using Excel 2013).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated - thank you in advance!

Comment: Needless to ask, but to double check, 1) Have you closed and opened the Excel files? 2) Have you restarted your computer 3) Is this the only thing that is not working or did not find anything else gone wrong?

Comment: Yes I have already tried the above, as well as opening the file on another machine.